# Finding the kth smallest element in a sequence where duplicates are compressed?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, selection

I've been asked to write a program to find the kth order statistic of a data set consisting of character and their occurrences. For example, I have a data set consisting of

```
B,A,C,A,B,C,A,D
```

Here I have A with 3 occurrences, B with 2 occurrences C with 2 occurrences and D with on occurrence. They can be grouped in pairs (characters, number of occurrences), so, for example, we could represent the above sequence as

```
(A,3), (B,2), (C,2) and (D,1).
```

Assuming than k is the number of these pairs, I am asked to find the kth of the data set in O(n) where n is the number of pairs.

I thought could sort the element based their number of occurrence and find their kth smallest elements, but that won't work in the time bounds. Can I please have some help on the algorithm for this problem?

Comment: This is the [selection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). It's discussed in many textbooks; the best algortithm is usually quickselect.

Comment: @larsmans yes, i agree with you, but i am struggling a bit to apply it on this contest, to have a program running with O(k) where k is the number of the pair made of charaters and their number of occurences.

Comment: On second thought, this question is more interesting than I thought. +1, but I don't know the answer :)

Comment: @larsmans wouldn't running quickselect on the number of occurrences in `(A,3),(B,2),(C,2),(D,1)` (i.e., on the numbers in the tuples) be equivalent to running quickselect on an array, `[3,2,2,1]`, so that O(n) in this case would equal O(k), which is the number of tuples?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I suppose, but the required modifications to the algorithm are not entirely trivial. The usual exposition of it expects random access into an array.

Comment: @larsmans, in this case, the number of pairs is 4; so my algorithm should run based on them, not the number of elements;

Comment: @גלעדברקן your suggestion could work but remember that, the tuples can be stored in any other and sorting them by their number of occurences will takes at least O(mlogm) which is already more than the O(m) required in this program.

Comment: @masheranosanchez thank you for you comment - it was not clear to me in your question if the data set we are given is `B,A,C,A,B,C,A,D` or `(A,3),(B,2),(C,2),(D,1)`. Based on your comment, I now assume it is the former.

Comment: @גלעד ברקן do you think it what you suggested can work on the former?

Comment: @masheranosanchez I am not too much of an expert, but if `k` equals the number of distinct elements in the data set, which is in the unexamined form of `B,A,C,A,B,C,A,D`, then I do not see how you can have any algorithm less than `O(n)` since you would need to pass at least once through the whole data set to know how many distinct elements there are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have access to a linear-time selection algorithm, here's a simple divide-and-conquer algorithm for solving the problem. I'm going to let k denote the total number of pairs and m be the index you're looking for.

- If there's just one pair, return the key in that pair.
- Otherwise:

  - Using a linear-time selection algorithm, find the median element. Let `medFreq` be its frequency.
  - Sum up the frequencies of the elements less than the median. Call this `less`. Note that the number of elements less than or equal to the median is `less` + `medFreq`.
  - If `less` < m < `less` + `medFreq`, return the key in the median element.
  - Otherwise, if m ≤ `less`, recursively search for the mth element in the first half of the array.
  - Otherwise (m > `less` + `medFreq`), recursively search for the (m - `less` - `medFreq`)th element in the second half of the array.

The key insight here is that each iteration of this algorithm tosses out half of the pairs, so each recursive call is on an array half as large as the original array. This gives us the following recurrence relation:

> T(k) = T(k / 2) + O(k)

Using the Master Theorem, this solves to O(k).